# ExcelLibrary - OutOfMemoryException when trying to open an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, exception, out-of-memory, excellibrary

I'm getting an error when trying to open an Excel Spreadsheet. I am using ExcelLibrary in Visual Studio 2015 and Excel 2010. Am I doing something wrong?

It errors at line 3.

---

`OutOfMemoryException was unhandled`

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`
`Additional information: Array dimensions exceeded supported range.`

---

```
1     string file = @"C:\\Users\user\Desktop\data.xlsx";

2     Workbook workbook = Workbook.Load(file);
3     Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
4     worksheet.Cells[2, 3] = new Cell(textBoxText.Lines[0].ToString());
5     worksheet.Cells[2, 4] = new Cell(textBoxText.Lines[1].ToString());
6     workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
7     workbook.Save(file);
```

Comment: How much ram do you have? watch your RAM usage when running the program

Comment: @JamieRees I have 8 GB of ram. It hovers around 4 while using the program with no large spikes

Comment: Why do you add the `worksheet` back to the Worksheets collecton? You didn't remove it, right?

Comment: @rene No, I do not remove it. However removing it doesn't solve the problem.